# Problem installing R-base in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, r

`sudo apt-get install r-base` produces de following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.5.3-1bionic) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.5.3-1bionic) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I was following [How to Install R on Ubuntu 18.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-18-04/) hopping it should be the same for ubuntu 16.04. I need to install the latest version of R in my cpu. thanks for your help.

Comment: The procedure *is* essentially the same, but for 16.04 you should have used `xenial-cran35/` in place of `bionic-cran35/`

Comment: I was able to install R but version 3.4.4. How can I get the latest version?

Comment: Did you add the `xenial-cran35/` repo and `sudo apt update` again after removing `bionic-cran35`? If you use the plain `xenial/` repo you will only get 3.4.x afaik

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, in system settings  >> software and updates >> other software I just remove bionic-cran35 packages from the list.